Ansible Playbook Succeeds on One GCP VM but has No Effect on Another Identical VM
I am encountering an issue with an Ansible playbook that runs successfully on one GCP Ubuntu VM us3tab01 but has no effect on another identical VM us3tab02. Both VMs are configured similarly, and Ansible can successfully ping both hosts.
create-file.yaml
---
- name: Create a file in the home directory
  hosts: tab_clusters
  become: true 
  become_user: tableau-admin
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: Create empty file
      file:
        path: "/home/tableau-admin/test.log"
        state: touch
        mode: '0644'

hosts.ini
[tab_clusters]
us3tab01 ansible_host=us3tab01 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=XXXX
us3tab02 ansible_host=us3tab02 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=XXXX

Steps Taken:
I've verified the following:

Successful ansible -m ping to both VMs
Identical playbook code
SSH key permissions for the user
I've tried Increasing Ansible verbosity(-vvv)
Manually SSH'ing into us3tab02 VM as a tableau-admin user and can successfully create a file with no issues.

Details:

Ansible Version: 2.16.7
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 on both VMs
SSH Connectivity: Verified, Ansible can ping both VMs successfully.
User: tableau-admin exists on both VMs with identical permissions.
Disk Space: Adequate on both VMs.
Filesystem: No errors detected.

Despite these checks, the playbook executes successfully on us3tab01 and us3tab02 but does not create the specified files in the us3tab02 interestingly the file is created successfully in the us3tab01 VM. The specific verbose output does not show any errors and executed success.
I've searched for similar issues on Stack Overflow, but haven't found a solution that works in my case. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The Ansible output for the task Create empty file is CHANGED for both hosts?
It's a long shot but I would try to validate that Ansible is actually connecting to the host you want (us3tab02). You could do a tail -f /var/log/audit.log in us3tab02 and check for the incomming Ansible connections.
Another thing to check is to run the playbook using a limit on the problematic host (--limit us3tab02). I remember some rare cases where Ansible had bugs on running a particular module on multiple instances.

Thank you. Yes the ansible output changed for both hosts. fyi

Good point. i checked the audit.logs, there are no ssh connections by ansible user for us3tab02 VM which makes sense now. But i'm not sure what's the reason for it given that i can successfully do ping test.

Probably the ansible connection is going to somewhere else, maybe another host like us3tab01 or localhost. Check what IP is being resolved from both host names using ping us3tab01 and ping us3tab02
